# Need help assigning array to new type Employee

Tags: java, arrays, class

My code currently runs. The problem is, I miss understood the assignment and I need to arrays of type Employee (so I need an additional class called Employee).

Currently, I have 3 arrays:

1. Saves Name info
2. Saves Address info
3. Saves Date info

I actually now need an array for each employee:

1. Employee1 saves Name, Address, Date info
   etc

As you can see, I have the number of emplyess you want to create set to variable n.

Main

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // Ask user to enter # of employee records to add
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Employee Database" + "\n\n"
                + "Enter the number of employees to add: ");
        final int n = input.nextInt();
        
        // Create arrays
                Name[] arrayName = new Name[n];
                Address[] arrayAddress = new Address[n];
                Date[] arrayDate = new Date[n];
        
        // For loop input questions over (n) employees
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println("- - - NEW EMPLOYEE - - -" + "\n");
            System.out.println("Basic Information");
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - -  - - -");
            System.out.println("Enter first name as <First>: ");
                String fn = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter last name as <Last>: ");
                String ln = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter employee ID as <1A45G>: ");
                String id = input.next();
                
            System.out.println("Address Information");
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - -  - - -");
            System.out.println("Enter street <123.High.Street>: ");
                String str = input.next();  
            System.out.println("Enter city <Springfield>: ");
                String cty = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter state <XX>: ");
                String sta = input.next();
            System.out.println("Enter zip code <54321>: ");
                String zip = input.next();
                
            System.out.println("Hiring Date Information");
            System.out.println("- - - - - - - - - -  - - -");
            
            
            System.out.println("Enter hiring month as <12>: ");
                    int mo = input.nextInt();   
                    
                    // While loop to alert of incorrect entry
                    while((mo >= 12) || (mo <= 1)) {
                        System.out.println("Incorrect format entered. Please try again: ");
                        System.out.println("Enter hiring month as <12>: ");
                        break;
                    }
            System.out.println("Enter hiring day as <31>: ");
                    int day = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter hiring year as <2023>: ");
                    int year = input.nextInt();

            // Save data to arrays
            arrayName[i] = new Name(fn, ln, id);
            arrayAddress[i] = new Address( str, cty, sta, zip );
            arrayDate[i] = new Date( mo, day, year );
            
            input.close(); 
                
        }
        
        // Print data from arrays
        System.out.println("Printing Employee list....." + "\n");
        // accessing array elements using the for loop
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            System.out.println(arrayName[i]);
            System.out.println(arrayAddress[i]);
            System.out.println(arrayDate[i]);
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Name

```
public class Name {

    // Name and ID number variables
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String idNumber;

    // Getters for the above variables
    public String getFirstName(String fn) {

        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName(String ln) {

        return lastName;
    }

    public String getID(String idd) {

        return idNumber;
    }

    // Parameterized constructor
    public Name(String fn, String ln, String id) {

        firstName = fn;
        lastName = ln;
        idNumber = id;
    }

    // Convert to String

    public String toString() {

        return "\n" + "Employee Name: " + firstName + " " + lastName + "\n" + "Employee ID#: " + idNumber;
    }

}
```

Address

```
public class Address {

    // Name and ID number variables
    private String street;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String zipcode;

    // Getters for the above variables
    public String getStreet(String str) {

        return street;

    }

    public String getCity(String cty) {

        return city;

    }

    public String getState(String sta) {

        return state;

    }

    public String getZipcode(String zip) {

        return zipcode;

    }

    // Parameterized constructor
    public Address(String str, String cty, String sta, String zip) {

        street = str;
        city = cty;
        state = sta;
        zipcode = zip;

    }

    // Convert to String
    public String toString() {

        return "Address: " + street + ", " + city + ", " + state + " " + zipcode;
    }

}
```

Date

```
public class Date {

    // Date variables
    private int month;
    private int day;
    private int year;

    // Getters for the above variables
    public int getMonth(int mo) {

        return month;
    }

    public int getDay(int dy) {

        return day;
    }

    public int getYear(int idd) {

        return year;
    }
    
    // Parameterized constructor
    public Date(int mo, int dy, int yr) {

        month = mo;
        day = dy;
        year = yr;
    }

    // Convert to String
    public String toString() {

        return "Hiring Date: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }
}
```

I have been struggling with this for 3 hours on how to make these changes and I simple cannot figure it out.

Ive tried adding a setName method in Employee class with something like:

```
`public void setName(String[] employeeName) {
        
        this.employeeName.setName(employeeName[0], employeeName[1], employeeName[2]);`
```

Comment: Instead of those three arrays, use one Employee[] and collect the instances of Employee there.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

If I understand well, you are near.
You only need one more class.

```java
public class Employee {
   private Name name;
   private Address address;
   private Date date;

   public Employee(Name name, Address address, Date date) {
      this.name = name;
      this.address = address;
      this.date = date;
   }

   // Your getters, setters : public Name getName(), public void setName(Name name), etc.
   ...
}
```

And you could create soon an `Employee[] employees`, if it's what you're looking for?

---

In the end of your `main` function, where you have:

```java
arrayName[i] = new Name(fn, ln, id);
arrayAddress[i] = new Address( str, cty, sta, zip );
arrayDate[i] = new Date( mo, day, year );
```

What about substituting this with something like:

```java
employees[i] = new Employee(new Name(fn, ln, id), 
   new Address( str, cty, sta, zip ), 
   new Date( mo, day, year ));
```

Where `Employee[] employees = new Employee[n];`?
Then you will keep the benefits of all the code you've already written, without changing it too much.

I think it should work.

Comment: This makes some sense to me. But you mentioned I need to add getters/setters. What about the getters/setters I already have in the Name class, Address class, etc? I am also still confused about what to do with the arrays I have

Comment: I've added a bit explanation in my answer.

Comment: Yes, that is more helpful thank you. So I implanted those. Everything appeared ok. Program ran, I was able to input employee data, but then got 

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
 at HelloWorld/EmployeeAssignment.Main.main(Main.java:66)"

Comment: Im still confused about the getter/setter question I had in my first comment. Under class Employee, shouldn't a getter of Name also include firstName, lastName, etc somehow?

Comment: I was able to solve, thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

In regard to the question asked in the comment,

> *"This makes some sense to me. But you mentioned I need to add getters/setters. What about the getters/setters I already have in the Name class, Address class, etc? I am also still confused about what to do with the arrays I have"*

The *Name*, *Address*, and *Date* objects will now be held within a separate object, thus only 1 array would be needed; of *Employee*.

Additionally, just utilize the getter and setter methods, when accessing the objects.

I believe you are expecting some sort of inheritance here, this isn't the case.
This is a basic data structure, which doesn't require any sort of transposition of data.

For example,

```java
class Employee {
    Name name;
    Address address;
    Date date;

    Employee(String fn, String ln, String id) {
        name = new Name(fn, ln, id);
    }
    
    void setAddress(String str, String cty, String sta, String zip) {
        address = new Address(str, cty, sta, zip);
    }
    
    void setDate(int mo, int dy, int yr) {
        date = new Date(mo, dy, yr);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "%s%n%s%n%s".formatted(name, address, date);
    }
}
```

And then, just adjust the input.

```java
// Create arrays
Employee[] employee = new Employee[n];
```

```java
// Save data to arrays
employee[i] = new Employee(fn, ln, id);
employee[i].setAddress(str, cty, sta, zip);
employee[i].setDate(mo, day, year);
```

```java
// Print data from arrays
System.out.println("Printing Employee list....." + "\n");
// accessing array elements using the for loop
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    System.out.println(employee[i]);
}
```

Comment: I was able to solve, thanks for the help